# How to split csv file into respective csv files based on date in first column (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large CSV with multiple years of electricity load data, and I would like to split it into multiple files on a month and year basis - i.e to return individual CSVs for Jan, Feb, Mar etc for 2013, 2014, 2015 etc.

I have reviewed a lot of the solutions in the forums, and have not had any luck. My current file is structured as follows;

---

01-Jan-11,1,34606,34677,35648,35685,31058,484,1730

01-Jan-11,2,35092,35142,36089,36142,31460,520,1730

01-Jan-11,3,34725,34761,36256,36234,31109,520,1730

01-Jan-11,4,33649,33698,35628,35675,30174,512,1730

---

The name of the column header in the date column is "SETTLEMENT DATE". I am familiar with using pandas and df's but cannot seem to wrap my head around how to do this one!

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

First you read your data from your `csv_file` and save your `cols` like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/input.csv')
cols = df.columns
```

then you add two columns to your `dataframe` which are `Month` and `Year`:

```
df['Year'] = df['SETTLEMENT DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[-1])
df['Month'] = df['SETTLEMENT DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

All you have to do left is to write your dataframe in separate `csv files` either by month or year with each `file` carrying the name of the `month` or `year` as follows:

```
for i in set(df.Year): # for classified by years files
    filename = "path/"+i+".csv"
    df.loc[df.Year == i].to_csv(filename,index=False,columns=cols)

for i in set(df.Month): # for classified by months files
    filename = "path/"+i+".csv"
    df.loc[df.Month == i].to_csv(filename,index=False,columns=cols)
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running into an issue using the x.split command - "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' " which could be a result of the import type. Is there an alternate function to use? Would it be str.split?

Comment: thanks for your feedback @tm553, in this answer i supposed your "SETTLEMENT DATE" was in string format but in other cases you can use `str(x).split`, `x.str.split` is only common if you're manipulating the whole columns but in this case x is actually an element of df['SETTLEMENT DATE'] column, so you need something that works on elements types like floats or other

Comment: Thank you for this! If I had data for a year and wanted to split this yearly data into quarters (Jan 1 - Mar 31, Apr 1 - Jun 30, etc.) and save as a new csv for the quarter - how might I do that?